# Can't change Link Datasource through ADO for accdb format

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I am trying to add a linked table to an Acccess database using ADO and ADOX (from excel).

However everytime I try, I receive the error: 
"Microsoft Access does not support linking to an Access database or Microsoft Office Excel workbook saved in a format that is a later version than the current database format."

Both the linked table and the target database are made using Access 2010 and are of the .accdb format. My code:

```
    Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog
    Set tbl = New ADOX.Table

    ' Open the catalog.
    cat.ActiveConnection = objConnection

    tbl.ParentCatalog = cat
    tbl.Name = "Promotions"
    tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource") = strCurrentPath & _
        "LocPrcCh.accdb"
    tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name") = "Promotions"
    tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link") = True
    tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Provider String") = _
        "MS Access;PWD=XXXXXXXXX;"

    cat.Tables.Append tbl
```

Returns the error after the last line. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Why would you use VBA to link tables from two different databases?

Comment: It's a solution that is written in excel because most users don't have access on their computers. The solution uses two main datasources a Promotions database (updated many times per day) and a large References database (which is updated once a month) both located on a server. The excel creates a local copy of both databases on the computer it is running on. Sometimes it needs to run queries on tables from both databases at the same time, for this I create a database with table links to both local databases. And I query this combined database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

My target file had the .accdb extension, but it was not in the 2007 format. When opened it said it was a 2002 - 2003 format access file.

The file was created in Access 2010, but the format was later changed I used a jetengine compacting function elsewhere in my program, which created a new version of the database in an older format.

Comment: Had a similar problem.  The hardest part was figuring out the format of the database.  I found this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) helpful in determining which MS Jet format is used in which MS Access version.